# Getting the currently logged in user from django view form

Tags: django, django-views

This is my model.

```
class Project(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.PROTECT, editable=False)
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
comission_owed = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, editable=False, decimal_places=2, default=0)
comission_paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, editable=False, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

And this is my model form:

```
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    required_css_class = 'required'
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].initial = self.user
```

and then here's my view:

```
def add_project(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProjectForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/add_project/?submitted=True')
    else:
        form = ProjectForm()
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:
            submitted = True
    return render(request,
    'add_project.html',
    {'form': form, 'submitted': submitted}
    )
```

I am trying to get the "user" filled by getting the logged in user but when loading the url "add_project/" where the form should load and let me submit I get an error that traces back to

```
KeyError at /add_project/
```

'user'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/add_project/
Django Version:     3.1.2
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:

'user'

Exception Location:     /ArtistShop/homepage/forms.py, line 12, in **init**
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version:     3.8.6
Python Path:

['/ArtistShop',
'/usr/local/lib/python38.zip',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.8',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages']

Server time:    Sat, 30 Jan 2021 19:16:12 -0500

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are not passing the user object to your `ProjectForm` in the else block.

```
def add_project(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        ...
    else:
        # Here, you should pass the user object too
        form = ProjectForm(user=request.user)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however after modifying it still returns an error now at line 14 being self.fields['user'].initial = self.user

Comment: I think you need to pass `user.id` to it, not the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_project(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        project = ProjectForm.save(commit=False)
        project.user = request.user
    else:
        .....
```

you can try this to get the user, and save in projectv.user